# Kafka streams : Aggregated results using time windows?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have following kafka stream application which I need to aggregated data using custom key. Key is changing but for the simplicity I have started with changing key to one field ( textId in SampleMessage). After group I need to get sum(amount) - ( amount is a double field in SampleMessage class). This is what i have came-up with.

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

builder = builder.addStateStore(Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("myStore"),
            Serdes.String(),
            Serdes.Long()).withLoggingDisabled());


KTable<String, SampleMessage> sampleMsgKtable = builder.table(TOPIC_NAME,
            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), sampleMsgSerde));

KGroupedTable<String, SampleMessage> groupByAggregation = sampleMsgKtable.groupBy((key, value) -> {
       String groupBy = getGroupBy(/**Params **/); // key is now textId
       return KeyValue.pair(groupBy, value);
    }, Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), sampleMsgSerde));

KTable<String, SampleMessage> reduce = groupByAggregation.reduce(
            (current, newValue) -> {

                double currentAmount = current.getAmount();
                double newAmount = newValue.getAmount();
                double total = currentAmount + newAmount;
                current.setAmount(total);

                return current;
            },
            (val, agg) -> {

                double valAmount = val.getAmount();
                double aggAmount = agg.getAmount();
                double diff = aggAmount - valAmount;
                agg.setAmount(diff);

                return agg;
            });

 KTable<String, String> finalData = myTransformer.transformToString(reduce);

 finalData.toStream().to("output");
```

I test above code with following messages ( using kafka-streams-test-utils-1.1.0). 
5 Messages are given as follows

```
1. textId = x , amount = 45
2. textId = x , amount = 45
3. textId = x , amount = 45
4. textId = x , amount = 45
5. textId = y , amount = 45
```

I get following

```
1. textId = x , amount = 45
2. textId = x , amount = 90
3. textId = x , amount = 135
4. textId = x , amount = 180
5. textId = y , amount = 45
```

Now I want to do this aggregation based on time window ( e.g aggregate on 5 min time intervals ). How to do that with KTables ?